# Automating git commands in C# does not remember Windows Credential Manager credentials

Tags: c#, process, linqpad, git-credential-manager

I have a LINQPad script that issues git commands via the cli using C# `Process` class and performs commands for several repositories at once.  The repositories are hosted on a TFS server.  Everything works fine in my terminal when doing commands manually.  The first command I issued, Windows Credential Manager prompted me and stored the credentials, and now I never get prompted on subsequent commands while in the terminal.  You can see the credentials in the git:* item below.

[image: Windows Credential Manager]

However, when I use the code below, I would hope...

1. It would just use the credentials already stored for that 'tfs' domain and just work, or
2. Only prompt me once and remember it for every command after.

Unfortunately, neither happens.  I've tried changing the code so that the `Process` object is re-used for all commands issued and that didn't help.  Is there a way to make this work so I don't have to enter credentials for every single command ran against each repository (which defeats the purpose of my program that processes repos in batch).

Note: The `local_os_password` passed in, is *not* intended to be used for git credentials.  I needed local credentials for the `Process` to run correctly.

```
async Task Main()
{
    await CallGitCommandLineAsync(@"C:\BTR\Evolution\Websites\ESS\ClientA", "pull", "local_os_password");
    await CallGitCommandLineAsync(@"C:\BTR\Evolution\Websites\ESS\ClientB", "pull", "local_os_password");
}

public async Task<string[]> CallGitCommandLineAsync(string repoPath, string command, string localPassword)
{
    var p = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe");
    p.Arguments = command;
    p.WorkingDirectory = repoPath;
    p.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.RedirectStandardError = true;
    p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    p.CreateNoWindow = true;

    p.UserName = Environment.UserName;
    p.Password = new System.Security.SecureString();

    foreach (var c in localPassword.ToCharArray())
    {
        p.Password.AppendChar(c);
    }

    using (var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
    {
        proc.StartInfo = p;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();

        var output = await proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
        var error = await proc.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync();

        var logRaw = string.IsNullOrEmpty(output) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(error)
            ? error.Split('\n').ToArray()
            : output.Split('\n').ToArray();

        proc.Close();

        return logRaw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the LibGit2Sharp library instead of shelling out to git.exe?

Comment: I have now.  But, after following directions, I'm stuck on `too many redirects or authentication replays`.  Trying to see if I can make it work.